# AWS Organization - How does one remove FullAWSAccess from children accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was following these [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_strategies.html) to create a Development account to REMOVE the root inherited **FullAWSAccess** SCP and only use the "Allow" Strategy to allow just EC2* RDS* CloudWatch* services. I'm doing this to prep for a Solutions Architect Professional exam and this exercise sounds perfect for understanding policy dynamics
Keeping that in mind I created an SCP **AllowOnlyEC2RDSCloudWatch** to allow just those 3 services and attached it to my account.

I thought I could now remove the **FullAWSAccess** policy inherited from root and just use this **AllowOnlyEC2RDSCloudWatch** policy that will force just those services to be allowed in my Development Account using the "Allow only xx" strategy suggested in the AWS documentation.

But even after attaching this **AllowOnlyEC2RDSCloudWatch**, I cannot detach the root policy from my Account thus indicating I have BOTH the **AllowOnlyEC2RDSCloudWatch** and **FullAWSAccess** policies . This seems to be opposite to what that link is suggested as a strategy to ALLOW only a specific set of services thus denying all else which is what I needed.

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing incorrectly?

So my Development Account > Policies page looks like this

> - AllowOnlyEC2RDSCloudWatch | Attached Directly
> - FullAWSAccess | Inherited from root // THIS I'm not able to DETACH

Comment: I think you should look into setting a `permission boundary` for your Developer account for restricting access beyond what's defined as the boundary.